# Is it possible to lock both borders in terminator splits?

Tags: terminator

When I open a Terminator window and split it into 4 terminals, I can change the terminal sizes by moving the borders (left-right, up-down). But depending on the order of my splits (either first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> first or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> first) one of the borders is not locked for all 4 terminals but just will just change the size of two terminals and the border afterwards is not aligned with the border of the other two terminals anymore. Is it possible to change this behaviour so that the borders are always aligned?